# Flask - pass variables to routes

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a page that will allow a user to download files that have been uploaded. Currently, I'm finding all of the files within a directory, passing them to the index page and printing them out. I then want each to have a download button, that when clicked will download the file relative to the file name. I cannot figure out how to pass the file name back through a URL so that I can use it on the download page.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, send_from_directory, send_file, abort
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads/'



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"] = {'TXT', 'PDF', 'DOC', 'DOXC', 'BIBTEXT', 'DBLP'}




@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = []
        with os.scandir('uploads/') as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                files.append(entry)
        return render_template('index.html', files=files)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

def allowed_ext(filename):
    if not "." in filename:
        return False

    ext = filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1]

    if ext.upper() in app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False



@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            file = request.files['file']

            if file.filename == "":
                print("File name must not be blank")
                return redirect(request.url)

            if not allowed_ext(file.filename):
                print("File extension not supported")
                return redirect(request.url)
            else:
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                print("File saved")
                return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/download/<file_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_file(file_name):
    file_name = file_name
    try:
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename=file_name, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head%}<title>File thingy</title>{% endblock %}

{%block body%} 

<h4 style='text-align: center;'> Directory Reader</h4>

{% if files is not defined %}
<h2 style='text-align: center;'>Click the button below to analyse the upload directory!</h4>
{% else %}
{% if files|length < 1 %}
<h2 style='text-align: center;'>No files found in this directory!</h4>
{% else %}
<table>
{% for file in files %}

<tr>
    <td>{{file}}</td>
    <td> 
        <a href='{{url_for(download_file, file_name=file)}}'>Download</a>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}




<form action='/' method = 'POST'>
<input type='submit' name='submitbutton' value='See Files'>

</form>
<button type="button" ><a href='/upload'>Upload file!</a></button> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What happens if two users upload `me.jpg`?

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing.? It looks to me like you might just be missing a `</td>` after your `<a>` tag.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying. I think the main issue I'm having is the thing that is being passed in the current version is "<Dir entry 'filename.ext'>", and thus it would try to download a file called that, rather than 'filename.ext' itself.